# Parsing the canonical name out of a distinguished name

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a small script that I can search people by their different properties and pull certain info. I pull the `Memberof` property, but it is kind of ugly with the full path. All I want is the canonical name.

I thought that I could pipe `Memberof` to `Where-Object` and match from `cn` to the first `,`:

```
select Name, EmailAddress, SAMAccountName, SN, Memberof |
  Where-Object -FilterScript:{$_.Memberof -match "cn*,"} | fl
```

Is this more complicated than I am thinking, or am I overlooking something? Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-match` operator expects a regular expression. Your second operand is `cn*,`, which means "a 'c', followed by zero or more times 'n', followed by a comma". To match text from `cn` to the next comma use `cn.*?,` instead.

In regular expressions the special character `*` has the meaning "zero or more times the preceeding expression", and a dot matches any character except newlines. The `?` makes the match non-greedy, so you get the shortest match instead of the longest match.

However, the `-match` operator is just matching an input string to an expression. It doesn't extract or remove anything from the input. Use the `-replace` operator for that:

```
select Name, EmailAddress, SAMAccountName, SN,
    @{n='MemberOf';e={$_.MemberOf -replace '^(cn.*?),.*','$1'}}
```

Comment: That work perfect thank you. The use of a hash table here never even crossed my mind, not to say it ever would of lol. I do have a question about the regular expressions (i been trying to get a better understanding). i was wondering "\v" (tab verticle) would that work to get each "CN" to a new line since new line expression can not be used and the powershell -ExpandProperty doesn't seem to work with multiple properties? Thank you again for the help.

Comment: @user3451049 I'm using a calculated property here, not a hashtable.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming what you're really after is common name (cn), I use this:

```
$regex = '^CN=(.+?),(?:CN|OU)=.+'
$cn = $dn -replace $regex,'$1'
```

Common names can have embedded commas. They have to be escaped with backslashes, but they can be in there, so using the comma as an anchor is unreliable.  If it's a leaf object, the next AD reference in the DN will have to be either an OU, or a container, so it will be either OU= or CN=.  I've always found this to be reliable.

Comment: Thank you as well. I was wondering is their a reason you made "regex" a variable instead of just having it written within the "$cn" line?

Comment: That's just a matter of personal preference.  It keeps the lines shorter and easier to read in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Long function incoming.  [Source](http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/translating-active-directory-object-names-between-formats).  Don't recall if I changed anything.

```
#Paste the function below into your session.  Here's an example pulling all my groups:
    Get-ADUser cookiemonster -Properties memberof | select -ExpandProperty memberof | Translate-ADName -InputType dn -OutputType canonical

#Looking at your question more closely, you aren't looking for the canonical name.  There are several output types to the function below, maybe NT4 is what you are looking for:
    Get-ADUser cookiemonster -Properties memberof | select -ExpandProperty memberof | Translate-ADName -InputType dn -OutputType NT4

#Add this function to your session before running the command above...
function Translate-ADName { 
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Translates Active Directory names between various formats.

.DESCRIPTION
Translates Active Directory names between various formats using the NameTranslate COM object. Before names can be translated, the NameTranslate object must first be initialized. The default initialization type is 'GC' (see the -InitType parameter). You can use the -Credential parameter to initialize the NameTranslate object using specific credentials.

.PARAMETER OutputType
The output name type, which must be one of the following:
  1779              RFC 1779; e.g., 'CN=Phineas Flynn,OU=Engineers,DC=fabrikam,DC=com'
  DN                short for 'distinguished name'; same as 1779
  canonical         canonical name; e.g., 'fabrikam.com/Engineers/Phineas Flynn'
  NT4               domain\username; e.g., 'fabrikam\pflynn'
  display           display name
  domainSimple      simple domain name format
  enterpriseSimple  simple enterprise name format
  GUID              GUID; e.g., '{95ee9fff-3436-11d1-b2b0-d15ae3ac8436}'
  UPN               user principal name; e.g., 'pflynn@fabrikam.com'
  canonicalEx       extended canonical name format
  SPN               service principal name format

.PARAMETER Name
The name to translate. This parameter does not support wildcards.

.PARAMETER InputType
The input name type. Possible values are the same as -OutputType, with the following additions:
  unknown          unknown name format; the system will estimate the format
  SIDorSIDhistory  SDDL string for the SID or one from the object's SID history
The default value for this parameter is 'unknown'.

.PARAMETER InitType
The type of initialization to be performed, which must be one of the following:
  domain  Bind to the domain specified by the -InitName parameter
  server  Bind to the server specified by the -InitName parameter
  GC      Locate and bind to a global catalog
The default value for this parameter is 'GC'. When -InitType is not 'GC', you must also specify the -InitName parameter.

.PARAMETER InitName
When -InitType is 'domain' or 'server', this parameter specifies which domain or server to bind to. This parameter is ignored if -InitType is 'GC'.

.PARAMETER ChaseReferrals
This parameter specifies whether to chase referrals. (When a server determines that other servers hold relevant data, in part or as a whole, it may refer the client to another server to obtain the result. Referral chasing is the action taken by a client to contact the referred-to server to continue the directory search.)

.PARAMETER Credential
Uses the specified credentials when initializing the NameTranslate object.

.FUNCTIONALITY
Active Directory

.EXAMPLE
PS C:\> Translate-ADName -OutputType dn -Name fabrikam\pflynn
This command outputs the specified domain\username as a distinguished name.

PS C:\> Translate-ADName canonical 'CN=Phineas Flynn,OU=Engineers,DC=fabrikam,DC=com'
This command outputs the specified DN as a canonical name.

PS C:\> Translate-ADName dn fabrikam\pflynn -InitType server -InitName dc1
This command uses the server dc1 to translate the specified name.

PS C:\> Translate-ADName display fabrikam\pflynn -InitType domain -InitName fabrikam
This command uses the fabrikam domain to translate the specified name.

PS C:\> Translate-ADName dn 'fabrikam.com/Engineers/Phineas Flynn' -Credential (Get-Credential)
Prompts for credentials, then uses those credentials to translate the specified name.

PS C:\> Get-Content DNs.txt | Translate-ADName -OutputType display -InputType dn
Outputs the display names for each of the distinguished names in the file DNs.txt.

.NOTES
    http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/translating-active-directory-object-names-between-formats
#>

[CmdletBinding()]
param(

  [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,Position=0)]
  [validateset("NT4","1779","SPN","canonical","GUID","DN","UPN","display","domainSimple","enterpriseSimple","canonicalEx")]
    [String] $OutputType,

  [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,Position=1,ValueFromPipeline=$TRUE)]
    [String[]] $Name,

  [validateset("NT4","1779","SPN","canonical","GUID","DN","UPN","display","domainSimple","enterpriseSimple","canonicalEx","SIDorSidHistory","unknown")] 
    [String] $InputType="unknown",

  [validateset("domain","server","GC")]
    [String] $InitType="GC",

    [String] $InitName="",

    [Switch] $ChaseReferrals,

    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $Credential
)

    begin {

      # Hash table to simplify output type names and values
      $OutputNameTypes = @{
        "1779"             = 1;
        "DN"               = 1;
        "canonical"        = 2;
        "NT4"              = 3;
        "display"          = 4;
        "domainSimple"     = 5;
        "enterpriseSimple" = 6;
        "GUID"             = 7;
        "UPN"              = 9;
        "canonicalEx"      = 10;
        "SPN"              = 11;
      }

      # Copy output type hash table and add two additional types
      $InputNameTypes = $OutputNameTypes.Clone()
      $InputNameTypes.Add("unknown", 8)
      $InputNameTypes.Add("SIDorSidHistory", 12)

      # Same as with previous hash tables...
      $InitNameTypes = @{
        "domain" = 1;
        "server" = 2;
        "GC"     = 3;
      }

      # Accessor functions to simplify calls to NameTranslate
      function invoke-method([__ComObject] $object, [String] $method, $parameters) {
        $output = $object.GetType().InvokeMember($method, "InvokeMethod", $NULL, $object, $parameters)
        if ( $output ) { $output }
      }
      function get-property([__ComObject] $object, [String] $property) {
        $object.GetType().InvokeMember($property, "GetProperty", $NULL, $object, $NULL)
      }
      function set-property([__ComObject] $object, [String] $property, $parameters) {
        [Void] $object.GetType().InvokeMember($property, "SetProperty", $NULL, $object, $parameters)
      }

      # Create the NameTranslate COM object
      $NameTranslate = new-object -comobject NameTranslate

      # If -Credential, use InitEx to initialize it; otherwise, use Init
      if ( $Credential ) {
        $networkCredential = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential()
        try {
          invoke-method $NameTranslate "InitEx" (
            $InitNameTypes[$InitType],
            $InitName,
            $networkCredential.UserName,
            $networkCredential.Domain,
            $networkCredential.Password
          )
        }
        catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
          write-error $_
          exit
        }
        finally {
          remove-variable networkCredential
        }
      }
      else {
        try {
          invoke-method $NameTranslate "Init" (
            $InitNameTypes[$InitType],
            $InitName
          )
        }
        catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
          write-error $_
          exit
        }
      }

      # If -ChaseReferrals, set the object's ChaseReferral property to 0x60
      if ( $ChaseReferrals ) {
        set-property $NameTranslate "ChaseReferral" (0x60)
      }

      # The NameTranslate object's Set method specifies the name to translate and
      # its input format, and the Get method returns the name in the output format
      function translate-adname2([String] $name, [Int] $inputType, [Int] $outputType) {
        try {
          invoke-method $NameTranslate "Set" ($inputType, $name)
          invoke-method $NameTranslate "Get" ($outputType)
        }
        catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
          write-error "'$name' - $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"
        }
      }
    }

    process {
      Foreach($item in $name){
        translate-adname2 $name $InputNameTypes[$InputType] $OutputNameTypes[$OutputType]
      }
    }
 }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your regex supports negative look-behind assertions, you can use `^CN=(.+?)(?:(?<!\\),|$)` ([usage example here](https://regex101.com/r/aU4pJ2/1)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at this task:

```
function ConvertFrom-DistinguishedName ($DistinguishedName) {

    $Domain = ($DistinguishedName -split ',DC=' | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^CN=' }) -join '.'
    $CNPath = ($DistinguishedName -split ',DC=' | Where-Object { $_ -match '^CN=' }) -split ',\w\w='
    [array]::Reverse($CNPath)
    ($Domain + '/' + ($CNPath -join '/')) -replace 'CN=' -replace '\\'
}

ConvertFrom-DistinguishedName "CN=Bradshaw\, Jeremy,OU=PowerShell,DC=stackoverflow,DC=com"
```

...and of course the output is below:

`stackoverflow.com/PowerShell/Bradshaw, Jeremy`